# Destroy object copies?

Tags: unity

I want to know how to destroy object copies.

```
    public GameObject sparks;

void Update() {

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider bulletv) {      

    if (bulletv.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        Instantiate(sparks,transform.position,transform.rotation);
        // destroy sparks copies after 2 seconds !!!
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried doing? You could just attach a simple script to the `sparks` that will "self-destruct" after 2 seconds

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Just I want to know how to destroy a copy of an object in this way. So, can you please answer the question ?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)? You can provide a second parameter to delay the destruction by some number of seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a reference to the object you instantiate, like this:

```
GameObject a = Instantiate(sparks,transform.position,transform.rotation);
Destroy(a, 2f);
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler ways to destroy a gameobject after it has been instantiated is to use the `Invoke` method, in a similar way demonstrated in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start() {
        Invoke("SelfDelete", 2);
    }

    void SelfDelete() {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the built-in delay capability in [the Destroy method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) for this? eg. `Destroy(target, 2.0f);`

Comment: @DMGregory probably not - I remember I once had issues with it (but that was back in version 4.4) and used this way. I haven't used it with the built-in delay since then. (Actually I don't even remember if it had the delay back then - it's been too long)